CarrierWave is creating bucket.domain for my minio s3 cdn
I want to use my minio cdn to add assets from rails using carrierwave.
My CarrierWave config looks like:
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
        config.fog_credentials = {
            :provider               => 'AWS',
            :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV.fetch("MINIM_SECRET_KEY"),
            :aws_access_key_id      => ENV.fetch("MINIO_ACCESS_KEY"),
            :region                 => 'ap-east-1',
            :host                   => "cdn.doamin.in",
            :endpoint               => "https://cdn.doamin.in:9000",
        }
        config.fog_directory  = ENV.fetch('DEPLOYMENT')=="STAGE" ? 'doamin-assets-stage': 'doamin-assets'
        config.fog_attributes = {
            debug_request: true
        }
    end

I know minio is compatible with aws and it works like wonder when i use it like the following
require 'aws-sdk-core'

Aws.config.update(
   endpoint: 'https://cdn.domain.in',
   access_key_id: ENV.fetch("MINIO_ACCESS_KEY"),
   secret_access_key: ENV.fetch("MINIM_SECRET_KEY"),
   force_path_style: true,
   region: "ap-south-1"
)

$cdn_client = Aws::S3::Client.new

uploaded = $cdn_client.put_object(key: key, body: params\[:file\], bucket: bucket, content_type: content_type)
if uploaded\[:etag\] != nil
file_path = "https://cdn.domain.in/#%7Bbucket%7D/#%7Bkey%7D"

How can set carrier wave config so that I don't get error when creating
for
class Model < ApplicationRecord
mount_base64_uploader :image_url, ModelImageUploader


in controllers
Model.create(params)

the error I get:
Exception === no address for domain-assets-stage.cdn.domain.in (Resolv::ResolvError)
there is no sub domain for my buckets the first part of this address is bucket followed by domain in carrierwave config.
I was expecting to use carrierwave just like how I use $cdn_object to store assets associated with models.

issue is force_path_style: true -- add that to the config.fog_credentials
